# VestaCP - Subdomain Folder

Tags: dns, subdomain

It's been a week since I want to achieve this with no luck. I've read a lot of tutorials but still can't get it to work.

I've got a DigitalOcean droplet with VestaCP and a couple of websites on it. Now, I want to add a subdomain to one of them and I just can't do it.

One of the simplest solutions I've read was:

> when adding a new domain add it like a subdomain for example
>   sub.domain.com and it will create a new web folder for it... it should
>   automatically configure your dns for you as well.. as long as your
>   using the same ip address as the original domain.com no need to touch
>   DNS records

Let's say my domain is test.com, what I want to do is set sub.test.com to point to test.com/sub.

I've enter via FTP to test.com and there's no 'sub' folder in there. Also try creating it my self with no luck.

Going to sub.test.com just trows ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED (wait a couple of hours for DNS propagation). And in VestaCP after setting the domain, a new DNS domain was automatically created.

I hope you can help me out. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Though it is a bit late, but I think it may help someone else. Have you solved your issue yet?
I am not sure from your question whether your web domain (of the subdomain) is working properly.
Is your web domain working and you just want to point your sub web domain to a folder? If this is your issue, then I suggest you to look at [https://vestacp.com/docs/#how-to-point-subdomain-to-dir](https://vestacp.com/docs/#how-to-point-subdomain-to-dir). It tells you how to do that with htaccess.

Comment: Thank you arkaroy! I'll give it a try. Actually I gave up on this because I couldn't solve it. I'll let you know if it helps

Comment: @ArkaRoy me again... I decided to finally give it a try! It works! thank you! If you like create and answer and I'll mark it as accepted

Comment: mmmm sorry I think still not working... Sadly